# Choosing between buffers in a Metal shader

Tags: metal

I'm struggling with porting my OpenGL application to Metal. In my old app, I used to bind two buffers, one with vertices and respective colours and one with vertices and respective textures, and switch between the two based on some app logic. Now in Metal I've started with the [Hello Triangle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/hello_triangle) example where I tried running this vertex shader

```
vertex RasterizerData
vertexShader(uint vertexID [[vertex_id]],
             constant AAPLVertex1 *vertices1 [[buffer(AAPLVertexInputIndexVertices1)]],
             constant AAPLVertex2 *vertices2 [[buffer(AAPLVertexInputIndexVertices2)]],
             constant bool &useFirstBuffer [[buffer(AAPLVertexInputIndexUseFirstBuffer)]])
{
    float2 pixelSpacePosition;
    if (useFirstBuffer) {
        pixelSpacePosition = vertices1[vertexID].position.xy;
    } else {
        pixelSpacePosition = vertices2[vertexID].position.xy;
    }
    ...
```

and this Objective-C code

```
bool useFirstBuffer = true;
[renderEncoder setVertexBytes:&useFirstBuffer
                       length:sizeof(bool)
                      atIndex:AAPLVertexInputIndexUseFirstBuffer];
[renderEncoder setVertexBytes:triangleVertices
                       length:sizeof(triangleVertices)
                      atIndex:AAPLVertexInputIndexVertices1];
```

(where `AAPLVertexInputIndexVertices1 = 0`, `AAPLVertexInputIndexVertices2 = 1` and `AAPLVertexInputIndexUseFirstBuffer = 3`), which should result in `vertices2` never getting accessed, but still I get the error: `failed assertion 'Vertex Function(vertexShader): missing buffer binding at index 1 for vertices2[0].'`

Everything works if I replace `if (useFirstBuffer)` with `if (true)` in the Metal code. What is wrong?

Comment: My suspicion is that when you're hard-coding the conditional, the compiler is smart enough to eliminate the branch that references the absent buffer, but when the conditional must be evaluated at runtime, it isn't. Since all declared buffer parameters must be bound, it trips the validation layer. You could just bind a few "dummy" bytes at the `Vertices2` slot (using `setVertexBytes`) when not following that path to get around this.

Comment: This might also be place to use function constants, although that's perhaps a bit advanced if you're just getting started with the basics.

Comment: @warrenm Yes, using a dummy buffer for `vertices2` works, but since it's a workaround I wanted to know the real reason behind it ... Anyway thanks for the input!

Comment: The real reason is that you're obligated to bind a buffer for every buffer parameter. The validation layer can't know that you aren't going to reference a buffer when access is gated by a run-time variable.

Comment: @warrenm I would have thought that not binding all buffers is valid, since when the if is hardcoded to true it works and `vertices2` is apparently not accessed. So if I really had to use a dummy buffer, then it would have to be the same size as `vertices1` because I can't be sure which part of it will be accessed, which is very inefficient. It seems to be like there must be another problem ...

Comment: As I said in my first comment, if the compiler can determine conclusively that a branch of a conditional is never taken, that branch will be omitted from the compiled shader via dead-code elimination. As for the buffers having to be the same size, that's not something that is (or can be) checked by the validation layer. The presence of the buffer is all matters for validation.

Comment: @warrenm Now I understand, sorry for my confusion. I see that every buffer must be bound and the compiler might optimise the second buffer away because it is never accessed when the if is hardcoded. If you add your comments as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: You could just pass the same buffer for both… no need to create a dummy buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're hard-coding the conditional, the compiler is smart enough to eliminate the branch that references the absent buffer (via [dead-code elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_code_elimination)), but when the conditional must be evaluated at runtime, the compiler doesn't know that the branch is never taken.

Since all declared buffer parameters must be bound, leaving the unreferenced buffer unbound trips the validation layer. You could bind a few "dummy" bytes at the `Vertices2` slot (using `-setVertexBytes:length:atIndex:`) when not following that path to get around this. It's not important that the buffers have the same length, since, after all, the dummy buffer will never actually be accessed.

Answer (score 0):

In the atIndex argument, you call the code with the values AAPLVertexInputIndexUseFirstBuffer and AAPLVertexInputIndexVertices1 but in the Metal code the values AAPLVertexInputIndexVertices1 and AAPLVertexInputIndexVertices2 appear in the buffer() spec. It looks like you need to use AAPLVertexInputIndexVertices1 instead of AAPLVertexInputIndexUseFirstBuffer in your calling code.

Comment: I updated the question to make this clearer. Each of these variables has a different value, so binding the buffers in different order than they are declared in the Metal code is valid.

Comment: Could you try the fix I suggested instead of just restating the you are correct? You are simply not binding the right buffers, the value in the buffer does not matter. Bind each buffer each time.

Comment: If you are trying to do something else, like only pass 1 vertex buffer into the shader, then just do that, pass a single buffer and choose the buffer at execution time. The approach you have implemented seems to be trying to select at runtime, but with condition logic in the shader. Your approach does not match the expectations of the Metal buffer binding logic.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get what you mean. The fix you suggested includes not binding `AAPLVertexInputIndexUseFirstBuffer`, which would be incorrect. Later you said that I should bind each buffer each time, which is a contradiction to what you first said. `AAPLVertexInputIndexUseFirstBuffer` is also declared as a buffer, which you seemed to have overseen. Yes, I am trying to pass only one of the two vertex buffers, but the problem is that they have different types (I updated the question to reflect this), that's why I thought I would have to declare both vertex buffers and then only bind one of them.